# Trapping network errors via XMLHttpRequest onerror handler

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, onerror

I'm trying to trap **network errors** such as **ERR_CONNECTION_RESET** via an onerror handler attached to the XMLHTTPRequest object **(native JS)**. I wrote a quick stub to see what was passed to the onerror handler, as part of my prelimiary research. Testing this stub, I found that the onerror handler received a ProgressEvent object, which does not contain anything useful for detecting the errors I'm seeking to trap - all it contains is a type property that contains the string "error".

Is there a way of obtaining the actual error object generated from within the onerror handler? Only I would prefer if possible to trap network errors within my AJAX code that is affected thereby, instead of using a global window.onerror handler that will trap *every* uncaught exception (and which will be extremely tedious to use).

The quick stub I used to find out what was passed to the onerror handler looks like this:

```
function TrapAJAXError(e)
{
var test = e;

}
```

Yes, I know, trivial in the extreme, but useful enough to let me find out what was passed to the handler.

Examining the variable 'test' in the debugger revealed that it was a ProgressEvent object, with no sign anywhere of any connection to an error object. When I deliberately triggered a network error, the onerror handler fired as expected, but I can find nothing in the ProgressEvent object that allows me to hunt down the error object that has been thrown.

Can I detect the nature of the network error in my onerror handler, or is this another of those quirks of JS that forces me to go through the horrible global error handler route?

Comment: Matters have just got a LOT worse. I tried a global window.onerror handler, and network errors such as ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED don't result in an error object being passed to the window.onerror handler. I thought Chrome was supposed to support the error object being passed?

Even stranger, the window.onerror handler is only called if an onerror handler is also attached to the XmlHttpRequest object. What's going on?